# How to create a config for your find and delete script

Tags: command-line, scripts, macosx, zsh, configure

I have a script that does the following task: Search in a directory for a file with the determined criteria.

`find Documents/Files/Logfiles/ -mtime +1d -type f '(' -name '*.log' -or -name '*[0-9].*' ')' -delete`

now I'd like to create a config file for this script where you can detriment, the extension, the modification time or the file name yourself.

I've never created a config file before and am very new to zsh, so I have no idea how to do that. the challange here is that we are supposed to work as this file is for a client.

Comment: Are you (or your client) using `macosx` as implied by your tag?

Comment: yes both me and the client are using macosx

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and which version of `find` are you running?

Comment: I'm currently working on a macos, using iterm2. as for the version of find I don't know. though I know im running zsh 5.8 if that helps.

Comment: You should be able to print the version with `find -version`. I ask because your syntax for `mtime` does not work for me.

Comment: typing ```fins -version```results for me in ```find: illegal option -- v
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]```

Comment: I think you should ask at some website for macos because `find` works different from here at Ubuntu.

Comment: You could ask on [unix.se] or [apple.se] but if you do, please clarify why you want a config file. That is a very complicated and hard to use approach. Why not simply pass the search string as an argument or an option when the script is launched? Using a config file just makes everybody's (yours and your users') lives harder for no benefit.

Comment: I just asked on Ask Different. the reason for the config its just that it is a task. on creating the script I mentioned it was optional to have the script lunch from a config file. upon asking how we could do that, we got tasked to figure it out ourself (as a challange) though we couldn't a result that could give us a lead on how to do it. though I appreciate the time and effort in helping us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a config file for this script, it imply that the script will have to read some parameter from a config file.

Config file
config.txt:

```
path=.
extension=sh
modtime=1
filename=test
```

Script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

lines=$(<config.txt)                 #read config.txt

for line in $lines; do               # parse each line and extract param-value keys
  if [[ $line = *"="* ]]; then       # if a word contains an "="...
     vars[${line%%=*}]=${line#*=}    # then set it as an associative-array key
  fi
done
find ${vars[path]} -mtime ${vars[modtime]} -type f "(" -name "*.${vars[extension]}" -or -name "${vars[filename]}.*" ")"
```

The other solution is to use the script with arguments and to specify path, extension, modification time or the filename as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

help()
{
   echo ""
   echo "Usage: $0 -p Path -e fileExtension -m modificationTime -f fileName"
   echo -e "\t-path Path where to search for"
   echo -e "\t-ext file name extension"
   echo -e "\t-modtime modification time e.g. +1d "
   echo -e "\t-filename file name"
   exit 1 # Exit script after printing help
}

while getopts "p:e:m:f:" opt
do
   case "$opt" in
      p ) pathFile="$OPTARG" ;;
      e ) extension="$OPTARG" ;;
      m ) modifyTime="$OPTARG" ;;
      f ) fileName="$OPTARG" ;;
      ? ) help ;; # Print help in case parameter is non-existent
   esac
done

# Print help in case parameters are empty
if [ -z "$pathFile" ] || [ -z "$extension" ] || [ -z "$modifyTime" ] || [ -z "$fileName" ]
then
   echo "Empty parameter(s), please check them...";
   help
fi

find $pathFile -mtime $modifyTime -type f "(" -name "*.$extension" -or -name "$fileName.*" ")"
```